# How to make an old CRT monitor (Syncmaster 753s) work on Windows 10 perfectly?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, display, crt

I used to have an LED monitor, but it used to have poor contrast levels, low refresh rate, poor color reproduction and when it finally got lines all over the screen (due to bonding issue in the LCD panel over age) I discarded it and switched to my old CRT monitor from Samsung. It is a Syncmaster 753s. It works fine (sharp and crisp image and great color and contrast) in my lubuntu OS (on two systems) and in my old windows 7 setup which I have as dual boot on machine 1. But the problem is the picture quality is a bit fuzzy (or hazy) and a bit irritating when used with windows 10 (which is setup as dual boot on machine 2 along side lubuntu).

I guess the problem is with the drivers in the windows 10 OS. Because the Intel HD Graphics software on the Windows 10 does not even detect the suitable resolutions for the monitor. Only going to settings>display>advanced setting, I can manually set the resolutions of the monitor...

Something is not just fine with the Windows 10 setup and my monitor. In Windows 7, using the graphics properties I can change even the H-size, V-size, Brightness, Contrast, RGB etc through the software under advanced settings.

When I tried to install the driver for the monitor in Windows 10 from [here](https://www.samsung.com/au/support/model/AN17LS7L/NZR/), (they are many out there) neither of them actually work. Either it says that "This software cannot run on this PC" in a blue dialog box. Or some says to run the setup.exe in compatibility mode (which I did : Properties>compatibility>Windows XP or Windows 7) but then it says "Could not find the monitor driver in INF file".

Do not know what the issue is. I do not usually use Windows 10. (Mainly use Lubuntu 20.04.3 or Windows 7). But at times I need to work on certain softwares which are developed only for Windows 10 (as Windows 7 is officially outdated).

So please could anyone help me. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: FWIW, CRT Monitors use a lot of power. I got a new View Sonic LED monitor for my new desktop machine and contrast is excellent. View Sonic come up with high marks on these kind of questions on the Internet.